# JSON output is blank

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code to return some JSON encoded results. If i double encode (i.e. put a json_encode in where I add the current row to the array) I get an an over-processed (lots of "/"'s everywhere) but complete output. As it is here, I get nothing.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","steph_stephen", "haltermann1!", "stephenh_tanks");
if (!$link){
    die("Conection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query="SELECT * FROM Tank";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $myArray = array();
    header('Content-type:application/json');
    while($tank = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //$myArray[] = json_encode($tank); if i leave this line in (and comment the line below) - i get the full but over-process json result
        $myArray[] = $tank; //without the line above no json string is returned
    }
    print json_encode($myArray);
}
else
{
    echo "Could not execute query";
    echo mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Below is a small part of the JSON that is return (albeit over processed)

```
["{\"tank\":\"001\",\"product\":\"Caromax 20HN B\\\/F\",\"prod_code\":\"51533\",\"tank_level\":\"7888\",\"volume\":\"1325818\",\"pump_volume\":\"1275282\",\"max_volume\":\"1759741\",\"tank_status\":\"For Test\"}"...
```

Comment: Show the difference between working code and not.  There's something else going on here, and if you check your error logs, it's likely to be obvious.

Comment: I have updated the code to show the line that works, and the one that doesn't...

Comment: Please view the source and show the json output

Comment: Also later on because `Conection failed: / Could not execute query` is not json it might break.

Comment: in your `while($tank = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`, add a log instruction. What's in `$tank` does it even fire at all?

Comment: Check `json_last_error()`. Typical cause: non-UTF8 encoded results from DB.

Comment: What you state the problem is is completely different.  One of your encodes is in the loop.  The other isn't.

Comment: The problem was non-UTF-8 encoding - once I enforced that from my webservice there were no problems! Thank you